# Missing Website Icon on Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, image, post, web

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
this is my chase: i am logged in at facebook and write a new post including our new wesite like this (www.domain.com). 
Facebook detects the url with title and meta name and keywords but not the ico. If i try  pages like www.youtube.com or www.google.com images shown up in the post like this: [image]

I need to know how to declarate it in my html that facebook detects a page image. Hopefully somebody can help me out here.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following tag in your `header`

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/yourimage.png"/>
```

Note that the image must have the minimum and maximum sizes permitted by Facebook (I don't know them so you need to look around in their developer documentation), also, if you already put the url on Facebook, it will use the cached content, so if you already tried this with no image, it won't get the image unless you use a different URL.

Comment: thx for ur help. this help me out! for others: the dimensions are 100x100 type: png!

Comment: do u know, if its possible to update the information like meta name aso. permernantly (cached content) which facebook is using?!

Comment: You can define the content you want Facebook to show, using OpenGraph tags (the one I gave you is an OpenGraph tag), look for them on the facebook's developer site. The information cached by Facebook is cached by a day or two, and there is no way I know of that can be changed.